# AWS RDS - Should I create a new cluster v a new database in an existing cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I am looking for any pointers on how to decide, or what indicates it is better, to create a new cluster on Amazon Web Services RDS.  Compared to simply creating a new database in an existing cluster.

I have read articles which seem geared more towards years ago when you were operating the physical servers but have not been able to find anything specific towards the current AWS RDS ecosystem.

If someone could please point me in the right direction it would be appreciated.

I have a few different projects which have different database requirements in terms of specifications.  Some will be not often accessed, whereas others will have much higher read/write.

That would seem to suggest separate clusters would be good because I could manage the specifications of the higher-use cluster and simply up those specifications while keeping a smaller instance size for the lower-use.

But I cannot help thinking that it might be better to simply keep all as separate databases on the higher-power instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's really a question of whether you want shared or separate resources.

Running on the same server **typically means lower costs**, but it also means **shared** storage, backups, RAM, CPU and security.

If you are the person who is **managing all the systems**, then certainly go for a single database server. However, if different teams and applications are being used, sometimes the separation helps to avoid conflict between people, systems and costs.

Comment: Hi John.  Thank you for that information.  It does make sense.  As a one or two-person 'team' then it makes sense to just have a single instance and we'll use separate databases on the one server for each different 'application'.